# How can I get Subversion to respect the SGID bit?

Tags: linux, unix, svn

On an Ubuntu server, I have a directory containing Subversion versioned files. I have used `chgrp bb *` to set the group owner.

I have also set the directory's SGID bit with `chmod g+s mydir` so that new files are created with this group:

```
drwsr-sr-x 4 mat bb  4096 Dec  4 21:37 mydir
```

This works fine if I create a new file with `touch test-touch`

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 mat bb        0 Dec  4 21:43 test-touch
```

But `svn update` does not have the same effect:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 mat mat    3006 Dec  4 21:44 test-svn
```

**How can I get Subversion to respect the SGID bit?**

Answer (score 1):

Going by [this discussion](http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2007-02/1082.shtml) on the SVN mailing list, it's not possible to preserve a file's permission bits in SVN, apart from the executable bit which has a special SVN property.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Version Control with Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/), the solution is to make sure the instance of svn or svnserve accessing the repository is running with umask 002, see [this](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.multimethod.html).

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same problem with subversion on a RHEL4 machine. After having migrated the repository to a RHEL5 machine (and thus to another version of subversion), the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Is the subversion executable running as user bb or mat? To find out, check the permissions on the svnserve binary(on my system it's `/usr/bin/svnserve`. Also check the group that it's owned by.

Comment: svnserve is owned by and group root -

ls -l /usr/bin/svnserve:

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 50432 Aug  7  2009 /usr/bin/svnserve